vectorisation fails due to unsupported control flow in loop
I have some C code that looks like (The full code on Compiler-Explorer: https://godbolt.org/z/aTGac8fco):
void foo(const float *restrict const input,
            float *restrict const output,
            const size_t input_buffer_size)
{
    #pragma omp simd
    for (size_t i = 0; i < input_buffer_size; i++)
    {
        float x;
        bool predicate;
        x = input[i];  // The [i] access is upsetting gcc but not clang.
        x = predicate ? x : -x;  // The warning goes away if I comment out this line. 
        ...
    }
}


Trying to get gcc-14 to vectorise this loop in the larger bit of code it is giving the complaint missed: not vectorized: unsupported control flow in loop. However, Clang-19 is able to vectorise this fine.
If I change the [i] to [0] the complaint goes away. Similarly if I remove the predicate, it goes away. I suspect GCC doesn't trust that the access will always be valid, but can't confirm this, or it doesn't like the ternary.
There is this very related question, but non of the tricks have helped. gcc auto vectorization control flow in loop
Currently I am not yet able to isolate out a MWE. (Working on it).
EDIT
If in the function body I set const float inputs[100] = {0}; (and rename the function signature to avoid a redefinition) then the complaint goes away. This furthers my suspicion that it is unsatisfied about the array length.
Since putting the code on compiler-exporer, though, my suspicions have also shifted towards the ternary.
Frustratingly, the compiler message is not the most precise.

What is Float  (not float)?

A general design hint: In glibc, the destination is usually the first param. And more generally it is func(dest,source,optons...). If you follow these rules, you don't have to think about the order of your own functions.

Float is a typedef for float32, missed this one, can remove.

If you change the input[i] to input[0] then you are not actually iterating over the array anymore, so there is nothing to vectorize.  I think that's a red herring.  The conditional x = predicate ? x : -x is a more likely culprit to make vectorization hard.  But how is predicate set, and does it depend on the contents of the array?

I was able to put together the [M]RE and uploaded the goldbolt link, although it's not especially minimal.

gcc duplicates the code between the 2 tests on predicate in order to have a single test. By that point, the code doesn't look like a plain selection between 2 values anymore, and the vectorizer has to give up.

As a hack, you can try -fdisable-tree-threadfull1 -fdisable-tree-thread1 -fdisable-tree-dom2 to see that gcc could vectorize without some other optimizations getting in the way.

get_table_index_from_float_format in your example returns an uninitialized variable??  (-Wall reports this.)

Btw, if testing vectorization, you probably want -march options to enable recent CPU features.  The baseline is just SSE2, I believe.

clang seems to take advantage of b being uninitialized, and assume it's always 0, meaning that polynomial_approximation is assumed to always return 0.0.    So if I read the code right, it's reducing to output[i] = (0.5 <= input[i]) ? -0.0 : 0.0 which is not terribly useful.  I think you need to improve your test case.

From the code of the godbolt-link: This expression x < 0.5f ? x : 1.0f - x is (mathematically) equivalent to fminf(x, 1.0f - x) -- which vectorizes much simpler. For a full solution you should provide code without UB (compile with -Wall -Wextra).

Assuming you actually  calculate an index, polynomial_approximation will need something like AVX2's gather instructions to get vectorized efficiently.

gcc seems to make the same assumption that the indeterminate value in b is always 0 (ecx is zeroed before the loop and never written again), but then it appears not to notice that poly_order_1_table_size_8_coef_0[0] etc could be optimized into constant 0.0; otherwise it could produce the same trivial code as clang.  (Actually even more trivial; because of -ffast-math it doesn't have to distinguish positive and negative zero, so it can ignore the input entirely and simply memset the entire output array to 0.0.)

You're de-referencing an uninitialised boolean predicate.

@SimonGoater In the real code this is initialised. Perhaps I should add another ... to the code example.

No, no more ... please! This isn't something that people are going to answer based on abstract principles about what kind of thing the code is doing. We need real, actual, working code that we can compile, read the asm, tweak, and compile again. It's a hands-on process.

Looks like I was able to appease GCC by writing my own version of the ternary operator.
Replacing
float x = p ? t : f;

with the cruder
#pragma omp declare simd
static inline float ternary(bool p, const float t, const float f) {
    return p * t + (!p) * f;
}


Did you check the code this generates? The ternary operator should generate a blendv instruction (for SSE4) or a series of bitwise operations (e.g., (p & t) | (~p & f), assuming the predicate is calculated from an SSE comparison).
